# commenting system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a blog like application where an author creates a post and the users without registering comment on the post the comment will be displayed if and only approved by the author, the help i want is regarding the database table, i have created a table which will hold the records such as name, email, phone, location etc. i have defined a new_id as foreign key to hold the id of the news to which it belongs.

[image]

is this the correct way of doing it as  the commenting system will be built on many to one relationship, or do i need to create another table to define foreign keys ? how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one to many relationship can be mapped with a foreign key in one of the tables, or with a junction table.

The way you do it is usually preferred. A user has a newsitem_id, and there can be multiple users to a newsitem.

If you want to store additional information, for example when the newsitem was added, a junction table can be used. Also, if you think that you may want to have multiple users to a newsitem, you need a junction table.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is basically sound.  (Though a better name for new_id would be good.)  You do not need an additional table to achieve what you describe.  Making new_id a foreign key would be beneficial in that it would enforce referential integrity (ie. if you delete a post, the comments would get deleted along with it.)  Do a search here for foreign key and there are several explanations of foreign key.

Comment: i have used new_id because i have been using the cakephp and i have been following the naming convention as mentioned by cakephp, like the table name should be plural, i have used new_id because i have a table called news i have ommitted the s and joined the id, that is how i have been doing in cakephp.. thank you for that kind reply..